# Fasting, what and when a Daniel fast is appropriate

Tags: fast-days, daniel-book-of

I would like to know, what is exactly a Daniel fast? when it is appropriate to do and how to do it?

Thank you for your reply

Justine

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Justine!

Comment: Given that the site is meant to accomedate people with very different backgrounds, it is usually useful to add references, links or sources, to the different ideas a post contains. For example, what a 'Daniel fast' is.

Comment: The reason Daniel abstained from certain foods was because they (obviously) they did not serve kosher meat in Nebuchadnezzar's court. I'm under the impression that the concept of a "Daniel fast" is of Christian origin.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct. If not, consider clarifying which additional information you want.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, classical Jewish sources do not place value on, or even refer to the 'Daniel fast', as a discrete regimen. Indeed, Daniel's diet seems to have been the result of his problem with the particular food he was served:

> But Daniel purposed in his heart that he would not defile himself with the king's food, nor with the wine which he drank; therefore he requested of the chief of the officers that he might not defile himself ([Daniel 1:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3401.htm#8)).

The issue is generally understood to have been that the food he was served was not kosher (cf. Ibn Ezra to Daniel 1:8).

The fast seems mostly popular among Christians ([e.g.](http://daniel-fast.com/)), and involves certain dietary restrictions primarily those which are always binding on Jews anyway, (although there are [different versions of the practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Fast#Modern_practice)).

Comment: But it may be appropriate if you're somewhere with no Jewish community and no kosher food available.  I've never been anywhere quite that bad, there were always at least kosher yogurts or something, but I wouldn't call myself a seasoned traveler.